# ESP32 OTA update including data folder in bin firmware

Tags: esp32, ota, arduino-esp32

I saw there are few libs and tutorial about esp32 OTA update but as far as I saw this is working only for the code and not for the data folder. In my case I have a web server which store all html, css, js etc under "data" folder. Is there any way to have OTA update including these files as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tools that you can use from the command line to do what you're asking.

First you'll need to make a binary file containing an image of the filesystem - you can't update individual files, you'll have to overwrite the entire filesystem, which means you'll lose any data your program might have stored there.

Then you'll need to do an OTA update of the filesystem.

To make the binary file you'll use [spiffsgen.py](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/spiffs.html#spiffsgen-py). You can download it from [here](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/components/spiffs/spiffsgen.py). You'll need a working copy of Python on your computer to use it:

```
python3 spiffsgen.py 409600 data filesystem.bin
```

You should replace

- `409600` with the size of the binary image of the filesystem - this must be a multiple of the flash page size, which should be 4096
- `data` with the name of the directory holding the files
- `filesystem.bin` with the name of the output file

The maximum size of the binary file will depend on the the partition scheme you choose for your ESP32's flash storage; obviously the minimum must be large enough to hold the files you want to copy.

Once you've generated the filesystem you can upload it via OTA using [espota.py](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/tools/espota.py). The same tool can upload firmware or filesystem images, and works with

```
python3 espota.py -s -r -f .pio/build/lolin32/spiffs.bin -I ip-address -p 3232
```

- -s is means transmit a SPIFFS filesystem rather than do a firmware update
- -r means display a progress bar
- -f is followed by the name of the file holding the filesystem image
- -I is followed by the IP address or hostname of the device you want to update
- -p is followed by the port number the ESP32 is listening on (usually 3232 for an ESP32, 8266 for an ESP8266)

Your application will need to use the [ArduinoOTA library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ArduinoOTA) in order to support this. The library has built-in support for filesystem updates; your Arduino code doesn't need to do anything special to support it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are no shrink wrapped solutions for updating files on a file system, so you get to create your own. Fortunately it's easy, because it's only data. You can either download a compressed archive (there are libraries supporting [tar.gz](https://github.com/tobozo/ESP32-targz) on ESP32 and probably many others) and update your files by decompressing this archive. Or, alternatively you can also update the entire file system partition if you have the means of creating an image file. E.g. the SPIFFS includes a utility script [`spiffsgen.py`](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/storage/spiffs.html#spiffsgen-py) which generates an image file, ready to be downloaded and flashed raw into the relevant partition using the [SPI Flash API](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/spi_flash/index.html).

Comment: There is! There's a tool called `espota.py` which can do this.